# Adding onpage CSS in Control Display template

Tags: display-template

I am trying to add CSS in `<style>` tag in Control Display template. But its not applying that CSS. Its taking inline CSS but not taking when adding inside `<Style>`Tag

PS: New to display tempaltes.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check in css file to major version (1.0)?
You need to add that line `$includeCSS` inside `<script>` not `<style>`

```
<script>
$includeCSS(this.url, "~sitecollection/Style Library/Slider/css/example.css");
</script>
```

Link: http://www.jasperoosterveld.com/2014/08/how-to-reference-your-custom-css-within-a-search-display-template/

Comment: Can we add css on html page directly without referring it. With <Style> Tag. The way we generally do with HTML page. <Style> h{font-size:30px}</style>

Answer (score 0):

move css content into a separate file and reference it in script tag

[more information here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138.aspx)

Comment: $includeCSS(this.url,"~sitecollection/style library/Slider/css/example.css");  is not working for me. Not sure why. Added CSS to style library.

Comment: Onpage will also work for me But I am able to give on page also.

Comment: did you get any error in the developer tools console? with default settings of style library, if css file is not published, you would get 404 not found error.